# Laravel - Single Model for Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use a single Model file for multiple tables.

Why???

The Table structure of all the tables is same

I have few columns to be stored as JSON Arrays and I would like to use Laravel's built in Json Serialization rather than manually serializing Arrays.

I have already read on laracast blog that it's not possible in Laravel but is there any other way to make it possible.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible because tables or models both are separate entities. May be for now your table structures are same but In near future, It may be changed. I advised you don't do this if you still found a solution.

Comment: But the models are very basic and are not likely to get changed, so it makes sense for me to do it instead of creating multiple Model Files @SaadSuri is there any option where I can avoid creating multiple model files...

Comment: In model you can define table (`protected $table = 'my_flights';`), so maybe if you set this variable in constructor based on some attribute passed to model, Maybe it will work, but you have to try it, I never did it.

Comment: This should work I feel, thanks, @Autista_z, I will try it and if it's working, you can post it as an answer and I will accept the Answer... Thanks again...

Comment: If it will work, let me know, then I will add it as answer :)

Comment: @Autista_z, your option is working, please post it as answer so that I can accept it...

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a base model that has the logic that is common to all the models, and then create your individual models that inherit from the base model.

```
class Auto extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'details' => 'json',
    ];

    public function getWheelsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->details->wheels;
    }
}

class Car extends Auto
{
    // models your "cars" table
}

class Truck extends Auto
{
    // models your "trucks" table
}

class Bus extends Auto
{
    // models your "buses" table
}
```

Or, you could create a trait with the common functionality and use the trait in all your child models.

```
trait HasJsonDetails
{
    protected $casts = [
        'details' => 'json',
    ];

    public function getWheelsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->details->wheels;
    }
}

class Car extends Model
{
    // models your "cars" table

    use HasJsonDetails;
}

class Truck extends Model
{
    // models your "trucks" table

    use HasJsonDetails;
}

class Bus extends Model
{
    // models your "buses" table

    use HasJsonDetails;
}
```

Or, another option, if the table structure truly is and will always be the same, would be to combine all your tables into one table and use single table inheritance to have multiple models all use the same table.

With this method, you would add a `type` field to your table to tell you which class to use to model the individual row. It also requires some customization, but you can find an STI package to use, or follow this forum thread for more information:

https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-eloquent-single-table-inheritance

This, of course, would still need to be combined with one of the methods mentioned above to share implementation logic across the multiple models.